# CFG for $w\#x$ where $|w| = |x|$ and $w \neq x^R$

Tags: context-free

How do I construct a context-free grammar for the following language?

$$L = \{w\#x \mid w, x \in \{0, 1\}^*, |w| = |x|, w \neq x^R \} $$

Answer (score 1):

A word belongs to your language if it has one of the following forms:
$$
\Sigma^i 0 \Sigma^j \# \Sigma^j 1 \Sigma^i \\
\Sigma^i 1 \Sigma^j \# \Sigma^j 0 \Sigma^i
$$
Given this, you should be able to construct a context-free grammar for $L$.

Comment: So would you say something like
$ \\ 
S -> A0B\#B1A | A1B\#B0A \\
A -> 0|1|epsilon \\
B ->0|1|epsilon$

Comment: Your grammar generates palindromes: $S \to A0B\#B1A \to 10B\#B1A \to 10\#B1A \to 10\#01A \to 10\#01$. It also doesn't guarantee that $|w| = |x|$: $S \to A0B\#B1A \to 0B\#B1A \to 0\#B1A \to 0\#1A \to 0\#10$.

Comment: From now on, I will not check any more "answers". The hints in my answer should be enough for you to solve the exercise.